# Is there a way to set the value of wsgi.input when testing?

Tags: python, unit-testing, wsgi

When using `wsgiref.util.setup_testing_defaults()` to set up a WSGI `environ` is it possible to set the `wsgi.input` value so that one can test HTTP POST requests?

Investigating the `wsgi.input` value created by `setup_testing_defaults()` shows that it's a `wsgi.validate.InputWrapper` object with `read`, `readline`, `readlines`, `input`, `close`, and `__iter__` methods, but no *write* methods.

**Edit:**
I'm working on Python 2.6.1

Comment: Which Python version are you using? I'm using Python 2.6.5, and the `wsgiref.util.setup_testing.defaults` creates an ordinary `StringIO` instance in the environment dictionary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the WSGI spec, the `wsgi.input` is just a file-like object. So even if your helper library assigns some weird object to the `environ['wsgi.input']`, you may replace it with any file-like object you want. In particular, with a `StringIO` object:

```
e = {}
setup_testing_defaults(e)
s = urlencode({'q': 'is there a way to set the value of wsgi input'})
e['wsgi.input'] = StringIO(s)
```